# How to do pattern substitution in Makefile?

Tags: shell, makefile, gnu-make

I have the script file with the following commands:

```
#!/bin/sh
val=echo $(PWD%/*)
val=${val##*/}
echo ${val}
```

what this does is if I have a path say a/b/c/d/e/f it will output as "e"
    This output is needed in my make file to compile particular package ,here "e". But how do I call these commands in my makefile?

Comment: Are you sure your shell script is giving output as e?

Comment: yes..even though if it doesnt give it is not the problem here.I want to know is there any way i can call my script commands in makefile

Comment: No; `val=echo $(PWD)` attempts to run the  command in the Make variable `PWD` with the shell variable `val` temporarily set to the  string `echo`. Presumably the OP actually wants `val='$(PWD)'` instead.

Comment: PWD is not the make variable

Answer (score 0):

Make has built-in [filename manipulation functions](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/File-Name-Functions.html); the desired result is much more easily obtained with

```
$(basename $(dirname $(PWD)))
```

in GNU Make.

Generally, you can use the `$(shell)` function to run arbitrary shell  commands and collect their output.